# how to parse a v3 onion domain

Tags: php, tor

I am trying to figure out how I can identify or programmatically extract the values **public key**, **checksum** and **version** from a v3 onion domain. Preferably in php.

The spec of the v3 onion domain is outlined here:
https://github.com/torproject/torspec/blob/main/rend-spec-v3.txt

Particularly interested in section 4.3.6

```
   The onion address of a hidden service includes its identity public key, a
   version field and a basic checksum. All this information is then base32
   encoded as shown below:

     onion_address = base32(PUBKEY | CHECKSUM | VERSION) + ".onion"
     CHECKSUM = H(".onion checksum" | PUBKEY | VERSION)[:2]

     where:
       - PUBKEY is the 32 bytes ed25519 master pubkey of the hidden service.
       - VERSION is a one byte version field (default value '\x03')
       - ".onion checksum" is a constant string
       - CHECKSUM is truncated to two bytes before inserting it in onion address

  Here are a few example addresses:

       pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscryd.onion
       sp3k262uwy4r2k3ycr5awluarykdpag6a7y33jxop4cs2lu5uz5sseqd.onion
       xa4r2iadxm55fbnqgwwi5mymqdcofiu3w6rpbtqn7b2dyn7mgwj64jyd.onion
```

If we take the first domain example: `pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscryd.onion`

if we drop the `.onion` suffix that should leave us with the base32 encoded string `pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscryd`.

I assume the public key is the first 32 bytes of the base32 decoded string? I have done the base32 decode here https://dencode.com/en/string?v=pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscryd&oe=UTF-8

Not sure if I am on the right track so far but how do I go about identifying the checksum and version components from this?

The php below seems to jive with the base32 online decoder

```
    $onionUrl = "pg6mmjiyjmcrsslvykfwnntlaru7p5svn6y2ymmju6nubxndf4pscryd.onion";

    //remove suffix
    $domain = str_replace(".onion", "", $onionUrl);

    //base32 decode
    $decoded = Base32::decode($domain);
    echo $decoded."<br>";
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. First 32 bytes are the public key, last byte is the version, everything else is the checksum then

Comment: i'm a little confused because it says the last byte (version) default value is `'\x03'` but i don't see how I can derive that from the last byte.

Comment: once base32 decoded the last byte is a square like utf8 symbol - does this need to be converted somehow to derive the version?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Where `$lastByte` is the last byte or character of the base32 decoded string. Using `bin2hex($lastByte)` or `unpack("H*", $lastByte)` both returned the value `03` which is consistent with the documentation that the default version is 3.